# why my name cannot get object name by using this->?

Tags: java, this

Why my `name` cannot get object name by using `this`?

```
public void setPhoneNumber(String n){
        phone_number1 = n;
    }

    public void setEmail(String n){
        email = n ;
    }

    public Person (String name, String address, String phone_number1, String email){
        this->name = name;
  getName();
        setAddress(address);
        setPhoneNumber(phone_number1);
        setEmail(email);
    }

    public Person (String name){
        getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not c++ but java :/

Comment: I know ,because I learned c++ before .I want to know how to modify it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the arrow operator work internally in java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898849/how-does-the-arrow-operator-work-internally-in-java-8)

Comment: The only valid place for the arrow operator `->` is in [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

Comment: Please study the Java Tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

As a C++ programmer, you should already have the basic idea of object-oriented programming, and the Java syntax in most cases should be familiar to you.

But in Java the equivalent of C++ arrow operator is `.`

The dot operator in Java is used almost for everything, just use:

```
this.name = name;
```

In Java arrow operator is used only in [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

The use of the `this` reserved keyword, is the same of C++.

> It can be
>   used inside the Method or constructor of Class. `this` works as a
>   reference to the current Object whose Method or constructor is being
>   invoked. The `this` keyword can be used to refer to any member of the
>   current object from within an instance Method or a constructor.

Comment: my object use new to construct, to locate memory.I need to use this.?

Comment: I've added a little more in my answer regarding the use of `this`

Answer (score 0):

`this->name = name;` change to  `this.name = name;`